# What is the right way to print data from my model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In my controller, I have:

```
def show
  @adjuster = Adjuster.find(params[:id])
end
```

`form_for` let's me print the data, but I don't want to use it because it is limited in certain respects. I `want` to use the regular `form` method.

I tried this:

```
 <%= form_for (@adjuster) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <b>Adjuster Name</b></br>
        <%= @adjuster.adjuster_name %>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I get an error saying:

```
@adjuster is empty
```

Comment: Hi @chase, Could you me show your `show.html.erb`?

Comment: I think stackoverflow went down for a bit. My show.html.erb is basically the above code with html tags around it.

Comment: It's possible that the gap between the `form_for` and the parentheses is the problem here... you should have either: `form_for(@adjuster)` or (preferably) no parens at all: `form_for @adjuster`. Aside: `form_for` can do almost everything that `form` can do -  what re you trying to do that it can't do? but then... if you are just printing data... you don't need a form at all. forms are for when you are asking a user to fill in new data to be submitted. you don't need a form of any kind if you are just printing out data.

Comment: Hey @chasedougherty, I just tested out this code, it's just completely ok, I don't seem anything wrong, working perfectly. I believe in your code not showing any error, you just make the `adjuster_name ` column has a value, I think the value is empty for  `adjuster_name `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested out this code (Just copy & paste), it's just completely ok, I don't seem anything wrong, working perfectly. I believe in your code not showing any error, you just make the `adjuster_name` column has a value, I think the value is empty for `adjuster_name`.

I just change the `column_name` such as `adjuster_name` to my own, and look generated HTML is like this

```
<form class="edit_adjuster" id="edit_adjuster_20" action="/adjusters/20" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="q/DPVxBU5gU5Gc1McT3USYRu21P6YBKeTfnwpOILO3xOAxKu25XqWJavy5alRxD1wMSVrtXCvb9l5ttsWzskAw==">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <b>Adjuster Name</b><br>
            Adjuster Name
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

That means the code is completely ok

```
<%= form_for(@adjuster) do |f| %> #=> or <%= form_for (@adjuster) do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <b>Adjuster Name</b></br>
            <%= @adjuster.adjuster_name %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

#=> controller
def show
  @adjuster = Adjuster.find(params[:id])
end
```